# Vimrc setting to allow free cursor movement on blank space

Tags: vim, caret

I can't recall the setting, but i remember using it some time ago.
The setting allows you to move the cursor beyond eol everywhere around blank space.

I checked :options, :help index and googled a lot, but couldn't find any mention of it.
Could've been the plugin, if that's so, please, tell me the name of it if you can.

Answer (score 4):

It's **set virtualedit=all**
:help virtualedit